# How to change the measurement unit from inch to cm in LiberOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to change the measurement units from `inch` to `cm` in LiberOffice. What can I do?
[image]

Answer (score 12):

1. Open the `Options` dialog.

   [image]
   <sup>**Click image to show animation**</sup>
2. Go to `General` under `LibreOffice Writer`.

   [image]
3. Change the measurement unit from `inch` to `Centimeter`.

   [image]
4. Click `OK`.
5. Now the units are changed to `cm`.

   [image]